# Rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, sqlite

I'm working on  ruby on rails project on hosting  machine  "nitrous"
I'm trying to push my files on Heroku  using command 
`git push Heroku master</code>`
               and this is the building log: 
       note:  building log is really big mess all what you need is to read site 
           Docs to know what they really support before trying to install
           something

Comment: This isn't a question, this is dump of a log. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help asking a good question.

Comment: sqlite is not supported on Heroku..try postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku does not support sqlite3. It instead uses a PostgreSQL database. I'd recommend following these docs for deploying Rails apps to Heroku:

Rails 4: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

Rails 5: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5

It's as easy as going to your Gemfile and changing `gem 'sqlite3'` to `gem 'pg'`. Be sure to run `bundle` afterwards.

You'll then need to set up a simple database.yml file, and then rebuild your schema for local development.

Follow the docs and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

in youe gemfile

```
gem 'pg'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

then

```
bundle install
```

push `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` to git.